# Stand-alone camel route, or separate routes inside ActiveMQ?

Tags: jms, apache-camel, integration, activemq-classic, messaging

I'm currently pondering how to best solve the following problem with Camel, and potentially ActiveMQ.

Data needs to be moved from a DB-table in Application A to a JMS Queue in Application B.

1) Create a stand-alone camel route, that fetches data from the DB-table, converts the relavent data to JMS message and sends it to the JMS queue in Application B.

- Pros: Simplicity
- Cons: Tight coupling between applications

2) Deploy an ActiveMQ instance, and create two separate camel routes inside the ActiveMQ instance. One route fetches data from the DB and puts is in an AMQ queue, and the second routes fetches data from the AMQ and pushes it to the JMS queue.

- Pros: Loose coupling, more scalable
- Cons: Additional components, More complex architecture to maintain

Which of the following two alternatives would you choose and why? 
I know what I'm leaning towards, but I won't tell you yet :-)

[image: Solution alternatives]

Answer (score 2):

Generally, we use apache camel to reduce the pain and complexity of enterprise integration. So if you can take data through a route from A to B in 10 or so lines of camel DSL - why not?

To me, I see more complexity in Alternative 2. Is there a reason you have in mind for using ActiveMQ?

Most often, you would use a custom ActiveMQ when you want some sort of guaranteed message delivery - but since application B has a JMS queue I doubt you really need ActiveMQ. There's a lot of headache in setting it up, maintaining it, and so forth.

With regards to coupling, I don't see that as a big issue. You are integrating between A and B, so there is bound to be *some* coupling. Your camel routes will need to know about the jpa / domain object format from Application A and the message format for Application B, in any case.

Performance wise, there is nothing to stop you solving performance problems in Alternative 1 via camel patterns for concurrent consumers, seda queues and the like.

Conclusion: I would go with simplicity (Alt 1), unless you have a specific and compelling reason to want to use ActiveMQ. Was that what you were thinking? ;)

Comment: Actually, it wasn't ;-) I was thinking to go with Alternative 2, using ActiveMQ. I realized that I forgot some important information about the scenario. There is a high probablibility (I would say 80%) that some other application will need the data coming from application A in the near future. That's what a main reason why I would go with solution 2.